# How can I submit the value of an autocomplete from material ui?

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I've installed material ui and I'm getting autocomplete options from jsonplaceholder and It works pretty fine and this is my code :

```
    const [ value, setValue ] = useState([]);
    const [ inputValue, setInputValue ] = useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then((res) => {
                setValue(res.data);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log('error happened');
            });
    }, []);

            <Autocomplete
                id="combo-box-demo"
                options={value}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
                style={{ width: 300 }}
                inputValue={inputValue}
                onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
                    setInputValue(newInputValue);
                }}
                onSubmit={() => console.log('hey')}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField 
                   onSubmit={() => console.log('hh')}
                   {...params} 
                 label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
```

Now the thing I want to achieve is when user selects an option , I want to console log something . 
I did try onSubmit on Textfield but it doesn't work .

How can I console log when the users selects an option from autocomplete or presses enter on the textfield ?

Comment: Have you tried the `onChange` method prop?

Comment: Well onChange doesn't work for me because it will run when user types everytime , I want to run a function when user selects an option or presses enter after typing in textfield

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi was correct. `onChange` is what you want. Setting `onChange` on the `Autocomplete` component (not the `TextField`) will make the change when a user SELECTS a new item for completion.

Comment: Providing `onChange` to the Textfield component will cause it to execute every time the user types, providing it instead to the Autocomplete component will trigger when the user selects an option. I'm not sure about the Enter key though.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi, it should still fire the event if the user has selected the new option using his keyboard and hits "enter".

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Thanks coding onChange in the autocomplete worked fine thanks again .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation, `onChange` needs to replace your `onSubmit` attribute on the `Autocomplete` component. This will fire whenever a user has selected a new option from the dropdown that is generated. If your `Autocomplete` were also a "freeSolo" field, it would NOT work when something were simply typed in and the user were to hit 'Enter'.

https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/

Comment: Thanks it workes when I select  an option but doesn't work when I press enter . How can I run a function when I press enter on the autocomplete?

Comment: Add a 'onKeyDown' listener to your `TextField` and in the function that is fired add an if statement with something like `if(event.key === 'enter'){ submitInput(event.value)}` (where `submitInput` is a function that sends it to the backend via w/e method you choose).

Comment: const handleEnter = (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'enter') {
   console.log('ff');
  }
 };        <TextField  onKeyDown={(e) => handleEnter(e)} {...params} />            I did this but didn't work , where am I mistaken ?

Comment: I figured it out it should be  e.keyCode === 13 instead of  e.key === 'enter' thanks for your help .

Comment: I typo'd mine. It should be 'Enter' not 'enter'. Doing keyCode will work as well, unless the user hits the 'Enter' from their 10-key pad. Then, it will fail iirc.